# Как через скрипт отправлять данные из одной таблицы в другую?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

**Задача:**

Необходимо дать менеджерам доступ к правке своей большой таблицы, из которой по нажатию кнопки данные попадают в другую таблицу в виде одной строчки.

Проблема в том, что менеджер не должен иметь прав просмотра конечной таблицы. А для того, чтобы скрипт работал, права на внесения изменений должны быть. Значит скрипт нужно делить и разворачивать как веб-приложение.

В первом скрипте (который ссылается) я получаю ошибку:

> Не удалось отправить запрос сервису https://script.google.com/a/***/exec

Во втором скрипте (на который ссылаются) ошибка такая:

> TypeError: Не удается прочитать свойство "postData" объекта undefined.

Вот пример моего скрипта:

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var TEST = spreadsheet.getRange("B4").getValue();
var TWO = spreadsheet.getRange("B5").getValue();
var THREE = spreadsheet.getRange("B6").getValue();
var FOUR = spreadsheet.getRange("B7").getValue();
var FIVE = spreadsheet.getRange("B8").getValue(); 

function myFunction() {
  var data = "[new Date(), TEST, TWO, FIVE, FOUR, THREE ];"
  UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://script.google.com/a/***/exec', {payload: data}); 
};
```

Эту часть развернул как веб-приложение:

```
var SHEET_ID = '***';

function doPost(e){
  SpreadsheetApp.openById(SHEET_ID).getSheets()[0].appendRow(e.postData);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Дубль https://toster.ru/q/597001

Answer (score 0):

Код, который должен отправлять данные

```
function recordToMain(){
  // Берет диапазон 'Источник!B4:B8' активной Таблицы, т.о. это встроенный скрипт
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('Источник!B4:B8')
  .getValues().map(function(row){return row[0];});
  var url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/ZZZ/exec';
  var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      ContentType: 'application/json'
    },
    payload: JSON.stringify(data),
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options); 
};
```

Код, который должен принимать данные

```
function doPost(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.openById('YYY') // Должна существовать
  .getSheetByName('Приемник')    // Должен быть лист 'Приемник'
  .appendRow([new Date()].concat(JSON.parse(e.postData.contents)));
}
```

1. Не забудьте, что вам необходимо каждый раз публиковать новую версию веб-приложения, когда вы внесли изменения в код "Применика".
2. Отправляйте `POST`, так понятнее и нет проблем с сериализацией `url`.

Пример с кодом (для краткости в одном файле) https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XJotz5g0AZPuxvpGrbcAzIeRmyNk2dclk8FIuG5UIUs/edit?usp=sharing

Дубль https://toster.ru/q/597001