# Как в python реализовать обработку excel файла с общим доступом?

Tags: python

На работе есть excel файл с общим доступом, таблица в котором обновляется сотрудниками на постоянной основе и довольно часто.
Примерный вид таблицы следующий:

| дата | название | процент | сумма |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| дата1 | продукт1 | XX% | 1234.5 |
| дата2 | продукт2 | XX% | 3456.7 |

Для начала я считываю информацию из этого excel с помощью библиотеки pandas и получаю датафрейм с данными из этого файла:

```
 import pandas as pd
file_name = 'путь и название файла'
sheet = 'название вкладки'
project_info = pd.read_excel(io=file_name, sheet_name=sheet)
```

Соответственно по каждому продукту я могу создавать каждый датафрейм:

```
price1 = {'продукт1': project_info.loc[['продукт1', 'сумма']]}
product1 = pd.DataFrame(data=price1)
```

Пользователи в течение дня довольно часто меняют значения в столбце сумма по каждому продукту.
Как в питоне реализовать, чтобы все новые значения суммы по каждому проекту  считывались питоном и добавлялись в датафрейм (ну или список) чтобы в конце дня/недели можно было выводить информацию по каждому продукту со историческим значениями за период?

Comment: Писать все в базу данных.

Comment: Может написать макрос, который бы тригерил скрипт на сервере? Тут есть как отправлять данные макросом https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/935149/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%8E